# Do I need to switch Laravel to Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-5

I have the same question about my current project.

---

- **Project type:** Something like shopping cart SDK.
- **Models:** 30+ (with extensions)
- **Extensions:** 15+
- **Tables:** 47
- **Relations:** every model have 3+ relations
- **The most performance demanding part processing:** 300ms

  ---

On start, I have 10 models with relations, that's why I choose Laravel as Framework, and I do not think about growing.

Now, I have 40 models with a lot of extensions and Laravel work fine.
My project is growing fast.
Now It's a big SDK with a lot of tables, relations, and extensions.

I need advice from experienced developers.

> Do I need to switch Laravel to Symfony, to reduce future problems with
>   performance?

I would be glad if you can advise me on this.

---

P.S.: I understand complexity with migration from Laravel to Symfony,

Comment: Laravel is great for small/medium projects. If you plan to expand your project even more migration to Symfony will be good choice. You will get better performance from refactoring existing project during migration to Symfony. It's more strict framework.

Comment: This whole notion of picking your framework based on the size of your project is just plain silly.  There are no Framework Monitoring Organizations watching your every move just waiting to prosecute you for using the wrong framework.  If you are comfortable with your current design then stick with it.  If you have specific reasons for wanting to use Symfony then go for it.  But project size as a criteria for switching?  Nope.

Comment: @Cerad  Did you even read the question? He's not satisfied with current design because of the performance. In most case scenario a framework with SOLID architecture will be preferable choice in bigger projects. Alternatively you may need some architect. You may feel comfortable to build huge app with Silex or Symfony Microkernel - others won't.

Comment: @ŁukaszD.Tulikowski Entirely possible I missed something.  I do have a tendency to skim.  But all I am seeing performance wise is that some sort of processing takes 300 ms.  Could you perhaps point out the section where the actual performance issues are detailed?  And perhaps a few hints on how a SOLID strict Symfony based app will solve them?  Feel free to be specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Performance-wise there is no big difference between frameworks. If you are coding right - they are all just the same.

But the problem is in this part **"if you are coding right"**.

You must always think about design, about responsibilities, about service layers, and to be consistent with your approaches.

And for this Symfony is much better. It's just a more convenient framework to go with SOLID. And it makes you think in a right direction.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: There is no any reason to change Laravel to Symfony.

Symfony has no layer for models handling. It's ORM library's responsibilities (usually we can use Doctrine in Symfony -- but it's possible to use another ORM libraries for that -- even Eloquent). And also it's not a big deal to use Doctrine for Laravel.

But obviously changing framework won't decrease the number of models -- so 40 models in Laravel still will be 40 models in Symfony. Because of this, there is no any advantage for decreasing of complexity.

Also there is no explicit dependency between framework and performance (generally, the DB is bottle neck).

Despite of opinion that Symfony automatically (and magically) increases programming skills -- it's wrong. So if someone able follow to SOLID principles, able to reduce cyclomatic complexity of the code, able to provide strong cohesion and loose coopling for the classes -- it doesn't sense what exact framework could be used. Actually Symfony doesn't force to use the best practices.

Therefore Symfony provides a lot of excellent components. But most of them can be used easily (and actually used) in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is good for medium websites. For big app i would always use symfony or zend.